# How to handle offline mode for Google visualisation in GWT

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-visualization, gwt2, offlineapps

I have a GWT application that uses many Google maps and charts. I want to have an offline mode where the user have the application installed on his the computer and without using the Google apps, he can continue using the other features.

For now the maps in the application throught a nullpointer error because they cannot initialize. I thought about checking the internet connection in EntryPoint and change the behaviour accordingly,  but I am hoping for a simpler solution. Any thought ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline
You cannot do that:

**Can I use charts offline?**

No; your computer must have live access to http://www.google.com/jsapi in order to use charts. This is because the visualization libraries that your page requires are loaded dynamically before you use them. The code for loading the appropriate library is part of the included jsapi script, and is called when you invoke the google.load() method. Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.load or google.visualization code to use offline.

**Can I download and host the chart code locally, or on an intranet?**

Sorry; our terms of service do not allow you to download and save or host the google.load or google.visualization code

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I thinks the terms and conditions are changed now. As you can save and download [JsAPI](http://www.google.com/jsapi), [ServiceBase](http://www.google.com/uds) to use charts offline.

But you still can't make ajax calls :[Ajax](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax)

Hope it will be available soon, cheers!